# convert C# Razor condition block to React.js code

Tags: reactjs, razor, single-page-application

How to convert code that has nested tags and conditions.
Razor C# code, The original source to be converted:

```
@if (isOnline == false)
    {
        <div class="container">
            @if (ViewBag.IsLink1 == "True")
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Index", "Home1")
            }
            @if (ViewBag.IsLink == "True")
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Index", "Home2")
            }
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
       <p>this is P tag...</p>
    }
```

and Failed attempt to convert code to Reactjs:

```
<Sample isOnline={false} IsLink1="True" IsLink2={"True"} />

function Sample(props) {
    return (props.isOnline == false) ?
        <div className="container">
            (props.IsLink1 == "True") ?<a href="/Home1/Index">Link1</a>:''
            (props.IsLink2 == "True") ?<a href="/Home2/Index">Link2</a>:''
        </div>
        : <p>this is P tag...</p>
}
```

The return code is rendered in html as follows :

```
<div class="container">(props.IsLink1 == "True") ?<a href="/Home1/Index">Link1</a>:'' (props.IsLink2 == "True") ?<a href="/Home2/Index">Link2</a>:''</div>
```

Comment: describe how your attempt is failed

Comment: @abolfazlshamsollahi, It does not render correctly in output Html.Not considering intermediate conditions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jsx you should wrap your js code with curly braces so your Sample component should look likde

```
function Sample(props) {
    return (props.isOnline == false) ?
        <div className="container">
            {(props.IsLink1 == "True") ?<a href="/Home1/Index">Link1</a>:''}
            {(props.IsLink2 == "True") ?<a href="/Home2/Index">Link2</a>:''}
        </div>
        : <p>this is P tag...</p>
}
```